# Hook up a Rect to a gesture recognizer for panning?

Tags: ios6, gestures

I have a bottomView (UIView) and a topView (UIView). 
bottomView has a red background and in IB, I've set topView to clearColor and Opaque to OFF. 
With the following code, I achieve my goal of creating a rectangle/window on the topView and punching a hole through to the bottomView:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGRect holeRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);

    self.opaque = NO;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Start by filling the area with the blue color
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill( rect );

    // Assume that there's an ivar somewhere called holeRect of type CGRect
    // We could just fill holeRect, but it's more efficient to only fill the
    // area we're being asked to draw.
    CGRect holeRectIntersection = CGRectIntersection( holeRect, rect );

    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill( holeRectIntersection );
}
```

NOW - I want to make the rectangle/window movable. I have set the ViewController up as UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and in the implementation file, have the following code in viewDidLoad that's worked for me in another project:

// create the pan gesture recognizer for each ImageView
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan1Recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]     initWithTarget:self
                                                                                         action:@selector(handlePan1From:)];

```
// set self as delegate for gesture recognition
[pan1Recognizer setDelegate:self];

// setup the selector for the pan gesture
pan1Recognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
pan1Recognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;

[XXX addGestureRecognizer:pan1Recognizer];

// ensure user interaction is ENABLED !!!!
[XXX setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Challenge is, the XXX above. In my other project, I had a subview in IB with an outlet defined so I could explicitly reference it. However in this project, I've created the rect in drawRect above and not sure how to make that connection.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *holerectView;
```

Then set the view to the rect frame:

```
 _rect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);

self.opaque = NO;
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Dont bother filling the rect with color; Just create background color for your view.

```
_holerectView = [[UIView  alloc] initWithFrame:_rect];
_holerectView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self addSubview:_holeRectView];
```

And here:

```
[_holeRectView addGestureRecognizer:pan1Recognizer];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to align the Rect I had created with the UIView that was under gesture control and solved it by moving them both together. Probably not the most elegant method, but it works and I've been stumped on this for over a week so naff to that and allons-y !